# How to plot gradient vector on contour plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient, contour

I have a loss function of two variables W1, W2 and an output z = F(W1,W2).

Now I plot the contour map of this loss function. Now say, I have calculated gradient vector at two points, therefore I have  two gradient vectors now. I want to plot these gradient vector on my contour plot but I have no idea how to procces. Any help is appreciated

```
enter code here
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

feature_x = np.arange(-50, 50, 2) 
feature_y = np.arange(-50, 50, 3) 

# Creating 2-D grid of features 
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(feature_x, feature_y) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1) 

z = 0.5*np.array((Y-X)*(Y-X) + 0.5*(1-X)*(1-X))

# plots contour lines 
ax.contour(X, Y, z, 10, cmap = 'jet') 
ax.grid(True)
ax.axis('scaled')
#ax.clabel(cp, inline=1, fontsize=10)  
ax.set_title('Contour Plot') 
ax.set_xlabel('feature_x') 
ax.set_ylabel('feature_y') 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [FancyArrowPatch](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html) to draw the gradients at a few selected positions.

```py
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
x1 = -20     # position of the gradient
y1 = 10
dz1_dx = 10  # value of the gradient at that position
dz1_dy = -5
arrow = FancyArrowPatch((x1, y1), (x1+dz1_dx, y1+dz1_dy),    
                        arrowstyle='simple', color='k', mutation_scale=10)
ax.add_patch(arrow)
```

[image: Contour Plot with Arrow]
Otherwise if you want to plot the whole vector field [quiver](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) might be an option:

```py
feature_x = np.arange(-50, 50, 2)
feature_y = np.arange(-50, 50, 2)

x, y = np.meshgrid(feature_x, feature_y)
z = 0.5*(y-x)**2 + 0.5*(1-x)**2
u = 2*x - y - 1
v = y - x

# Normalize all gradients to focus on the direction not the magnitude
norm = np.linalg.norm(np.array((u, v)), axis=0)
u = u / norm
v = v / norm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.plot(feature_x, feature_y, c='k')
ax.quiver(x, y, u, v, units='xy', scale=0.5, color='gray')
ax.contour(x, y, z, 10, cmap='jet', lw=2)

arrow = FancyArrowPatch((35, 35), (35+34*0.2, 35+0), arrowstyle='simple',
                        color='r', mutation_scale=10)  
ax.add_patch(arrow)  # NOTE: this gradient is scaled to make it better visible
```

[image: Gradient Field]

I added the `line y = x` in this plot and marked the point where this lines intersects with a contour line. Here you can see clearly
that:

> Gradients are orthogonal to level surfaces

So for your point `(80, 80)` the gradient `(79, 0)` is correct even so the general shape of isolines maybe suggest that there should be be a part in y-direction.
But if you look along the line y=x you see that the gradients there are always only in x-direction.

Comment: I updated my answer and included a second example where I plot the whole vector field,
hope this makes things clearer. But yes for the position / coordinates `(80, 80)`  the gradient is `(79, 0)`.